# Cauchy filters in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, filters

Some terminology: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

- A filter $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal P (X)$ is *Cauchy* if $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists x\in X: B_\epsilon(x)\in \mathcal F$.
- A filter $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal P (X)$ is *round* if $\forall F\in \mathcal F \exists \epsilon>0 \forall x\in X:B_\epsilon(x)\in \mathcal F \implies B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq F$.
- A Cauchy filter $\mathcal F$ is said to be *minimal* if no filter that is properly contained in it is Cauchy.

I found an article that remarks, as a matter of fact, that round Cauchy filters and minimal Cauchy filters coincide. Showing that a round Cauchy filter must be minimal is straightforward. But I can't immediately see how to prove the other implication. So, how does one show that a minimal Cauchy fiter must be round? Also, any references for the standard constructions of metric theory convergence by using filters (I know it's not strictly required, as sequences suffice, but still, I'm curious) are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: With your permission, I slightly modified the formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it would be easy to solve this by referring to the sequential completion, but that might be considered cheating.

I will use $N_\epsilon(A)$ to denote the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of a set $A$.
For a given filter $\mathcal{F}$ the family 
$\{ N_\epsilon(A) \mid \epsilon > 0,\, A \in \mathcal{F} \}$ is the base of a
filter $\mathcal{F}^\circ \subset \mathcal{F}$. Clearly if $\mathcal{F}$ is 
a Cauchy filter, then so is $\mathcal{F}^\circ$.

I claim that $\mathcal{F}^\circ$ is also round.

**Proof:** 
Take an arbitrary $V \in \mathcal{F}^\circ$. By construction, there are $\epsilon > 0$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $N_\epsilon(A) \subset V$.
Put $\delta = \epsilon / 3$. Now if there is some $x$ such that 
$B_\delta(x) \in \mathcal{F}^\circ$, then $B_\delta(x)$ meets $N_\delta(A)$, which means that $x \in N_{2\delta}(A)$, and therefore $B_\delta(x) \subset N_\epsilon(A) \subset V$.

To conclude: for every Cauchy filter there is a smaller, round Cauchy filter,
therefore any minimal Cauchy filter is round.

P.S.: I have not really investigated it, but it seems this might apply more generally to uniform spaces.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Basically the same way, I believe; substitute sets of the form $U[x]$ for $U\in\mathscr{U}$ and $x\in X$ for $\epsilon$-balls.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: I was merely suggesting the basic idea, not implying that one should use **every** entourage. Obviously in the metric $\epsilon$-balls are derived from a specific base. However, the little reading that I did in response to this question suggests that the choice of base doesn’t actually matter; whether that’s true for the obvious generalization of this definition, or whether the general definition isn’t the obvious generalization, however, I don’t know.

Comment: Thanks @Niels! Interestingly (to me at least), the same construction you give can also be shown to give the minimal Cauchy filter refined by the original filter. And (most interesting, to me at least) these constructions crucially use the symmetry of the metric. If symmetry is dropped, then neither of these results remains true. There are quasi metric spaces with no minimal Cauchy filters, and it is possible that a minimal Cauchy filter is not round (round Cauchy filters are still minimal though).

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: As I wrote, I did not really think it through. I think that for topological groups there is an analogue using an arbitrary neighbourhood base of 0. That there might be a common generalization to uniform spaces is pure guesswork. If you are really interested, I would suggest posting this as a separate question.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Actually, I would guess further that *round* might be defined like: for every set in the filter, there is a base for the uniformity, such that all "balls" from the base with centres in the set are contained in the set.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: It looks like this would offer a rather elegant way of constructing the completion of a metric space. Is that the context in which you came across it, or are there other applications?

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen the context was indeed completion. The completion of a metric space is thus the space of all minimal Cauchy filters on the space and the obvious metric. The wider context is completions of quasi-metric spaces, where there things are more subtle (see my previous comment).